# SQL error Access Denied when connecting to db from VS

Tags: sql, wpf, visual-studio

I have set up a database (QCDB) in my SQLEXPRESS instance. I have added a user (QCast) with serveradmin, sysadmin, and public server roles enabled at the server level. The user has db_owner role at the db level. But when connecting to the db with the below command in VS

```
string strConn = "Data Source=STA15-DT-ADM\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\QCDB.mdf;User Id=QCast;Password=QC@st;   Connect Timeout=30";


SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
string dbget = "SELECT WOnum WOstatus FROM WOdetail";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(dbget, con);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Results");
ad.Fill(dt);
WOgrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
cmd.Dispose();
con.Close();
```

I get the following error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\QCDB.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\QCDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.'

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Some process already has the file open. Maybe the file has already been loaded into SQL Express? (Local DB, the mode of loading databases on demand, is not generally compatible with opening the file in other tools, including VS, at the same time as using it in an application. (This is why I stick with the full SQL Server, in Developer edition.)

Comment: must not be the location as I have opened another db in the same directory

Comment: How do I check if a process has the file open? I have detached the db from SQL Mgmt Studio

Comment: Sys Internals has `handles` and Process Explorer, both of which can find all processes with a handle to a file (latter is easier to use with its find function).

Comment: Process Explorer comes up dry

Comment: In that case I would suspect the "A database with the same name exists" part of the error message

Answer (score 0):

I got this one after more Google

I simplified the connection string and it took right off. not sure why.

```
 string strConn = ("Data source = [Server Name]; Initial catalog = [db name]; User id = XXXX; password = XXXX");
```